# Ember.js: transitionTo route, then to dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

I have a Router set up with accounts, and account/:account_id options. When the user lands on the index page of my app I transition them to the accounts route.

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts', function(){
        this.resource('account', { path: ':account_id'});
    });
});

Social.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('accounts');
    }
});
```

What I'd like to do is to transition them to a specified :account_id route based on some criteria. At the moment I just want to get the first account in the array and use that. But in the future it could be a way to transition them to the last account they were viewing. Something like this:

```
Social.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('accounts/:account_id');
    }
});
```

The docs give "detail" but don't provide an example, only offering the following:

> **transitionTo (name, models)**
>
> Transition into another route. Optionally supply a model for the route
>   in question. The model will be serialized into the URL using the
>   serialize hook.

I've tried the following:

```
this.transitionTo('accounts/4');
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The route accounts/4 was not found

this.transitionTo('accounts', Social.Account.find(1));
Uncaught More objects were passed than dynamic segments
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I put together others' answers and some fiddling and came out with this answer:

define your routes like:

```
this.resource('accounts', function () {
    this.route('account', {path: '/:account_id'});
});
```

redirect:

```
this.transitionTo('accounts.account', accountObj);
```

But if you are loading from server, you need the `accountObj` object loaded before redirect:

```
var accountObj = App.Account.find(1);
accountObj.one('didLoad', this, function () {
    this.transitionTo('accounts.account', accountObj);
});
```

I set up [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cenic/XNyme/6/) with complete example

Comment: Your fiddle didn't seem to work so I updated it with calls from CDNjs.com: http://jsfiddle.net/XNyme/9/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like transitionTo is deprecated in favor of transitionToRoute.

Nonetheless you can achieve the reroute by having the original declaration be `this.resource('account', { path: '/:account_id'});` and then the transition with the single created object should work.

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying the route path properly and you should have a route under the resource, not another resource. It should be like this:

```
Social.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('accounts', function(){
        this.route('account', { path: '/:account_id'});
    });
});

Social.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('accounts.account', Social.Account.find(1));
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay. Implementing this code gets me two things. 1) The URL changes as expected. 2) I'm getting a console error of `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The route account was not found`.

When I land on `/` the URL changes to `/#/accounts/1` which is what I would expect, but nothing loads and the console error appears.

Comment: I forgot to add a path to the root accounts resource.

Answer (score 1):

With latest Ember (1.0.0-RC-6), this works perfectly.

**Router:**

```
this.resource('accounts', function () {
    this.resource('account', {path: '/:account_id'});
});
```

**To redirect:**

```
this.transitionToRoute('account', Social.Account.find(1))
```

Comment: It just works with ember 1.1.3+pre.e0ffbf84. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your /:account_id is a resource you need to transitionToRoute 'account'. You also need an AccountRoute accordingly.

If /:account_id was a route not a resource you would transitionToRoute 'accounts.account' and your route handler would be called AccountsAccountRoute.