# Problems transitioning to route from the controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller called application.js in that I have done below code :

```
setSectionAppForEmailPDF:function(currentCompnay,CurrentProperty,currentSection,currentPage)  

{  
     this.set("currentPage", currentPage);  
     var that = this;  
     this.set('currentSection', currentSection);
     var path = "/" + currentCompnay + "/" +CurrentProperty+"/"+currentSection; // Path == '/trilok/pathak Test/test'
     this.transitionToRoute(path);  //does not call the route ,not working   //this.transitionTo(path);     //does not call the route ,not working
```

}

Route code ::

```
App.TestRoute = App.PageBaseRoute.extend  

({   
     model: function() {},  
     setupController: function(controller, model) {  
     controller.set("test", 1);  
     this._super(controller, model); },  
})
```

and routing is defined like ::

```
App.Router.map(function(){  
      this.resource("test",{path:"/:company_id/:property_id/test"});  
    });
```

from all defined as well as the commented code i am not able to call the route

can any one tell me that what and where i am going wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `transitionToRoute` use the name of the route and not the path. So in your example above that would be "test".

**Update, 2015-05-08**

The problem (routing with dynamic segments) you try to solve is a common and well documented topic. You find good documentation at http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/ and there is another stackoverflow question with a nice example at [Ember.js: transitionTo route, then to dynamic segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100499/ember-js-transitionto-route-then-to-dynamic-segment)

=> Check the accepted answer of that stackoverflow question. It is exactly what you try to do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried that one but still not getting any positive result can you please guide me further  ??  it is very important

Comment: Added an update to my answer. Hope that brings you a step further. As I stated there, you should find plenty of examples for the specific problem you try to solve.

Comment: yes i have changed the code and your comment was very helpful thank for the help and keep helping !!!!